# Why react-select is breaking when I am using @react-google-maps/api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-select

I am facing a weird issue at the moment, I am trying to use `react-select` in my `create-react-app` project which is showing up the accessibility text, which are supposed to be hidden.

[image: in closed]

and when I click to open the dropdown, I see,

[image: open state]

These are the things I have followed

- `yarn add react-select@latest`
- `import Select from 'react-select'` added to my import list
- `<Select options={options} />` in my shared component list

And when I created a new project using `create-react-app test-react-select` and followd the following steps, works in this.

Can I have a few suggestions about what could be the things making the issue?
Code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, forwardRef } from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { string, number, shape, oneOfType, arrayOf, func, bool, oneOf } from 'prop-types';
import Select from 'react-select';

const Dropdown = forwardRef(({ label, deafultdropdownValue, deafultdropdownLabel, filterDropDown, dropdownList, textLabel, onClick, postion, name, darkBorder, className, errorMsg }, ref) => {

  return (
    <div className={classnames('dropdown', className, postion)}>
      {textLabel ? <div className="text-label utility-heading-4">{textLabel}</div> : ''}
      <Select options={dropdownList} />
      {errorMsg && <span className="error">
        {errorMsg}
      </span>}
    </div>
  );
});

Dropdown.propTypes = {
  label: string,
  deafultdropdownLabel: string,
  filterDropDown: bool,
  dropdownList: oneOfType([arrayOf(
    shape({
      label: string,
      value: oneOfType([string, number])
    })
  ), arrayOf(string)]),
  textLabel: string,
  onClick: func,
  postion: oneOf(['upward', 'downward']),
  name: string,
  className: string,
  darkBorder: bool,
  errorMsg: string,
  deafultdropdownValue: string
};

Dropdown.defaultProps = {
  filterDropDown: false
};

export default Dropdown;
```

There few old codes not used as I had my own dropdown which I am trying to replace with `react-select`

[image]
This class not adding styles. This is where the issue I see.

EDIT1. Finally figured the issue, not the solution tho.
The issue is when I am using `"react-select": "^3.0.8",` with `"@react-google-maps/api": "1.7.10",`.
Any idea how do I fix it?
https://codesandbox.io/s/usegooglemap-repro-x3q37

Comment: can you share the file in which you are using the dropdown?

Comment: Added the file.

Comment: Oh, I am using scss. Would that create an issue?

Comment: Sure I will remember that. Though the image was to show how the UI is braking. And the last one "demonstrating rendering bugs". But I get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `Select` tag you must be use `value` attribute which store the values for dropdown list data.

```
<Select options={options} value={DisplayData}/>
```

**`DisplayData`** is a variable which store the dropdown-list data which is going to select.

Comment: without `value` module is working in new create-react-app.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone facing the same kind of issue using `<LoadScript/>` rather useLoadScript or if you remove `preventGoogleFontsLoading: true` from useLoadScript config works great.

For more details follow this thread.
https://spectrum.chat/react-google-maps/general/react-google-maps-api-braking-react-select~86032a91-5a4b-4dbb-99fa-b1e1f7000e98